# Nullpointer Exception for mocking final method

Tags: java, elasticsearch, mockito, testng, powermockito

Getting NullPointerException when **trying to mock** [Aggregations.getAsMap()](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/blob/v7.1.1/server/src/main/java/org/elasticsearch/search/aggregations/Aggregations.java#L82)

I have already tried other different ways by using PowerMockito.doReturn(map).when(aggs).getAsMap() but still facing same issue

```
@PrepareForTest(Aggregations.class)
public class TestExample extends PowerMockTestCase {

    @Test
    public void testMyMethod() {
        Aggregations aggs = PowerMockito.mock(Aggregations.class);
        Cardinality cardinality = Mockito.mock(Cardinality.class);
        Map<String, Aggregation> map = new HashMap<String, Aggregation>();
        map.put("sample", cardinality);
        Mockito.when(aggs.getAsMap()).thenReturn(map);
    }

}
```

```
Mockito.when(aggs.getAsMap()).thenReturn(map);
```

while debugging aggs value is containing below value

```
{Aggregations$MockitoMock$485838759@3084} Method threw 'java.lang.NullPointerException' exception. Cannot evaluate org.elasticsearch.search.aggregations.Aggregations$MockitoMock$485838759.toString()
```

Using testng and below version of jars

powermock-api-mockito-2.0.2.jar

mockito-core-2.23.0.jar

Comment: Try `PowerMockito.when(aggs.getAsMap()).thenReturn(map);`. Mockito seems not able to mock `final` method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `NullPointerException` comes from the invocation of the `getAsMap` method.

Using `Mockito.doReturn(map).when(aggs).getAsMap();` instead should solve that issue.

However there seems to be a bug in `PowerMockito` as writing it like this is not supposed to trigger the invocation of the `getAsMap()` method (which still happens).

I suggest you create a bug ticket in their [bugtracker](https://github.com/powermock/powermock/issues) for this issue.

---

If you enable final mocking for `Mockito` (see [here](https://static.javadoc.io/org.mockito/mockito-core/2.23.0/org/mockito/Mockito.html#Mocking_Final))) running the test is successful.

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class TestExample {

    @Test
    public void testMyMethod() {
        Aggregations aggs = Mockito.mock(Aggregations.class);
        Cardinality cardinality = Mockito.mock(Cardinality.class);
        Map<String, Aggregation> map = new HashMap<String, Aggregation>();
        map.put("sample", cardinality);

        Mockito.doReturn(map).when(aggs).getAsMap();
        Assert.assertEquals(map, aggs.getAsMap());
    }
}
```

---

Another option might be to work with a real `Aggregations` object instead:

```
@Test
public void testMyMethod() {

    Cardinality cardinality = Mockito.mock(Cardinality.class);
    Mockito.when(cardinality.getName()).thenReturn("sample");

    List<Aggregation> list = new ArrayList<>();
    list.add(cardinality);

    Aggregations aggs = new Aggregations(list);
    Map<String, Aggregation> map = aggs.getAsMap();

    Assert.assertEquals(1, map.size());
    Assert.assertEquals(cardinality, map.get("sample"));
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I went with second approach creating real object and it worked. Will raise issue in bug tracker

Comment: @Developer , if above answer work for you, you should accept it as correct answer.

Comment: @Developer: Did you add a bugticket? If so, can you add the link as a comment?

Answer (score 1):

You are getting the exception because 'getAsMap' is a final method and mockito makes an actual API call instead of a mock call. This is because Mockito does not support mocking final methods and classes by default.

**Solution**: You need to include a mockito-extension plugin to support this functionality and it's very simple.

Check https://www.baeldung.com/mockito-final for the steps.